# How to debug Express js server code on Node using Visual Studio Code by Attaching to running process

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, express, visual-studio-code

I have:

- latest Visual Studio Code
- Express js
- Node js

This is my Attach configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    // List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "node",
            // // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
            // //"address": "localhost",
            // // // Port to attach to.
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the gulp task starting the application:

```
gulp.task('server', function (cb) {
    exec('mongod', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
      cb(err);
    });
    exec('node server.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
      cb(err);
    });
})
```

And this is the result of running Attach

```
request 'attach': cannot connect to runtime process (timeout after 10000ms)
```

What I'm doing wrong and why? How can I attach Visual Studio Code debugger to running Node app and debug server.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see this timeout error if the server isn't running when you try to attach the debugger. The client starts the language server so make sure you have started the client in order to have a running server.